# Angular cli error on components creation in spec file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using Angular-cli to create components is generating a consistent error on the .spec files on line 17

//let component = new TodoListComponent()
  // expect(component).toBeTruthy();

Comment: This looks like something that should be submitted as a bug on the CLI repo instead of an SO question.

Comment: Thanks, sent it in.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kinda of bad to do this, but I usually just delete that file and everything works again. From what I know that file is used just to check if something is wrong in your component.

For example:
const Var1 = "Should be this"